# display a list into excel cells

Tags: c#, excel

I want to display a list into excel cells with c#.The problem is that only the last item of the list is shown into the excel sheet. any help?
here is my code:

```
 Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Nb de fonction";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "list de fonction supprimé";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "list de fonction ajouté";
        foreach (var item in listfunc1)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 8] = item;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[7, 8] = item;
        }
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "list de commentaire supprimé";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 16] = "list de commentaire ajouté";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 19] = "list d'entête supprimé";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 16] = "list d'entête ajouté";

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\Documents\\csharp-Excel.xls");
```

Comment: It's because you're putting all the items into the same two cells, so each item overwrites the previous one, and the item that's left there at the end of the loop is the last item in the list.  Use a variable for one of the cell indices, and modify the variable on each iteration of the foreach loop; that will cause each item to be written to a different cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing this:

```
foreach (var item in listfunc1)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 8] = item;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[7, 8] = item;
    }
```

To this:

```
   int i=0;
   foreach (var item in listfunc1)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3+i, 8] = item;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[7+i, 8] = item;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: even with this I've got the same old result.

Comment: Could you show me how did you get the `listfunc1` values?

Comment: this is how did you get the listfunc1 List<string> listfunc1 = c.checkfunction(this.txtDirectory1.Text, this.txtDirectory.Text); foreach (string item in listfunc1) { MessageBox.Show("les entete de fonction modifié dans la version 1: " + item); } in the MessageBox it shows tow item of the list.sorry i can only comment –

Comment: Thanks for the response @user3801697. Did you try to inspect what are the values for `listfunc1` when you Debug? Is it different values or the same values?

Comment: listfunc1 return differnt values

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes and it works now

```
 int row = 3;
        int col = 8;
        foreach (var item in listfunc1)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = item;
            row++;
            if (listfunc1.IndexOf(item) == listfunc1.Count - 1)
                col = 1;

        }
```